# How to update PickerInput following above input selections

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I can't seem to figure out how to update the PickerInput based on previous inputs for my map selection. It seems that if I make choices in a descending order it sorts and filters properly but when I try to make choices in a reverse order it does not filter correctly and will allow me to select an input that does not have data for the annual range, wilderness, species, or life stage.

I have included the stripped down UI and server to show inputIds. Basically if a user selects a yearly range I want the wilderness input to update based on available wilderness for that year range selection. I then want the species to update based on wilderness and year range. Then finally I want the life stage of to update based on the year range, wilderness, and species available.

I am close with what I currently have. I have noticed the life stages selection is not working correctly. Let me know if you see any issues how I approached the UI and Server. I am sorry I could not include the data as it contains sensitive species location

UI

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  
  
  #includeCSS(here("NPS_ShinyApp/theme.css")),
  
  theme = theme,
  
  
  titlePanel(""),
  
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(8,
                    h1(strong("National Park Service App - RIBBiTR ")))),
  
  
  navbarPage("", inverse = T,
             
             tabPanel("Home", icon = icon("info-circle"),
                      fluidPage(
                        fluidRow(
                          h1(strong("Disclaimer"), style = "font-size:20px;"),
                          
                          column(12, p(""))),
                        
                        fluidRow(
                          h1(strong("Intended Use"),style = "font-size:20px;"),
                          
                          column(12, p(""))),
                        
                        fluidRow(
                          h1(strong("Data Collection"),style = "font-size:20px;"),
                          column(12, p(""))))),
             
             
             tabPanel(title = "Site Map", icon = icon("globe-asia"),
                      
                      sidebarLayout(
                        
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          sliderInput(inputId = "site_year",
                                      label = "Select an annual range",
                                      min = 2005, max = 2021, 
                                      value =  c(2020, 2021),
                                      sep = ""),
                          
                          pickerInput(inputId = "wilderness",
                                      label = "Select a wilderness",
                                      choices = c("yosemite", "goldent_trout", "desolation"), decreasing = T),
                                      multiple = F,
                                      selected = ""),
                          
                          pickerInput(inputId = "species",
                                      label = "Select a species",
                                      choices = c("buco", "hyre", "ramu"),
                                      selected = "",
                                      multiple = F),
                          pickerInput(inputId = "stage",
                                      label = "Select a life stage",
                                      choices = c("adult", "juv", "egg"),
                                      selected = "",
                                      multiple = F)),
                        
                        mainPanel(leafletOutput(outputId = "site_map", width = 900, height = 500)))
                      
             )
             
             
             
             
  ))
```

Server

```
# leaflet map with date, species, and site as reactive 
    output$site_map <- renderLeaflet({
      
      
        leaflet() %>% 
            addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery") %>% 
            addMouseCoordinates() %>% 
            setView(lng = -119.36697, lat = 37.923288, zoom = 7) %>% 
            addMeasure(
                position = "bottomleft",
                primaryLengthUnit = "feet",
                primaryAreaUnit = "sqfeet",
                activeColor = "#3D535D",
                completedColor = "#7D4479")
  })


    # observe events to update wilderness and years based on selection for leaflet map
    observeEvent(input$site_year, {
      
      updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "wilderness", 
                        choices = unique(data$wilderness[data$date == input$site_year[1:2]]))
    })
    
    observeEvent(c(input$site_year, input$wilderness), ignoreInit = TRUE, {
      
      updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "species", 
                          choices = unique(data$species[data$date == input$site_year[1:2] & data$wilderness == input$wilderness]))
       
    })
    
    observeEvent(c(input$site_year, input$wilderness, input$species),ignoreInit = TRUE, {
      
      updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "stage", 
                        choices = unique(data$visual_life_stage[data$date == input$site_year[1:2] & data$wilderness == input$wilderness 
                                                                & data$species == input$species]))
   
    })
```

server

```
if (!require(librarian)){
  install.packages("librarian")
  library(librarian)
}

# librarian downloads, if not already downloaded, and reads in needed packages

librarian::shelf(shiny, tidyverse, here, janitor, sf, lubridate, leaflet, shinyWidgets, leafem, bslib, thematic, shinymanager)

# themeing
theme <- bs_theme(
  bg = "#b2d1b9", # green background
  fg = "#2d302e", # cream text foreground
  primary = "#0417c2", # hyperlinks
  secondary = "#506e57", # messages
  success = "#506e57", # operation succeeded
  info = "#506e57", # light blue from bar
  warning = "#C3512C",# yellow
  danger = "#FACE00", # orange red
  base_font = font_google("Open Sans"), 
  heading_font = font_google("Source Sans Pro"))
```

Comment: Try updating in this order:  `observeEvent(input$site_year, {...})`, `observeEvent(input$wilderness, ignoreInit = TRUE, {...})`, `observeEvent(input$species , ignoreInit = TRUE, {...})`

Comment: That is really close also. I have noticed when I include a range, say 2020-2021 the filtering is not correct. For example, years: 2020-2021 in wilderness: yosesimite for species buco should have 3 visual life stages but only one is appearing. Is the method I am using to sort by a range of years correct?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot test it since there is no sample data.  Perhaps you can create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using `gapminder` or other available datasets.  Also, may be you should use `%in%` instead of `==` for years.

Comment: well that did it. I am 90% certain it is filtering correctly now. Thank you so much